# How to sum values inserted in DataGridView cells in VB2010?

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem on summing up two values inserted in specific cells in DGV. This process happen during run time. The result of summing should be display in another specific cell.

I have tried the code below:

```
    Private Sub dgdTax_CellContentClick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgdTax.CellContentClick

    '======================================== CALCULATION ==============================================='

    'to calculate r4rm1
    Dim r2rm1 As Double
    Dim r3rm1 As Double

    Try
        r2rm1 = CDbl(dgdTax(1, 2).Value)
    Catch e1 As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(e1.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    Try
        r3rm1 = CDbl(dgdTax(1, 3).Value)
    Catch e2 As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(e2.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    dgdTax(1, 4).Value = r2rm1 + r3rm1

End Sub
```

But it didnt work. It shows message error "Conversion from type DBNull to type Double is not valid."

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect dgdTax(1,2).Value or dgdTax(1,3).Value are null in the database.
Apologies, I don't know the VB syntax off hand but in C# you would test that the Value is not of type DBNull e.g

```
if (!(dgdTax(1,2).Value is DBNull)) { 
// do some stuff 
}
```

Taking a stab at VB

```
If Not dgdTax(1,2).Value is DBNull then
//do stuff
End If
```